# Como criar uma variável categórica no R?

Tags: r

Tenho uma base com colunas: `USUARIO`, `MÊS`, `ANO` e `compra_mês`. Gostaria de criar variáveis *dummy* baseado em `compras_mês` por `USUARIO`, a cada mês do ano.

```
   USUARIO MÊS    ANO      compras_mês
     <int> <ord> <dbl>       <int>
 1      37 jan    2019           1
 2      37 set    2018           1
 3      37 out    2018           4
 4      37 nov    2018           3
 5      37 dez    2018           3
 6      49 out    2018           1
 7      49 nov    2018           1
 8      49 dez    2018           1
 9     107 jan    2019           2
10     107 set    2018           1
```

Como exemplo, o meu objetivo seria deixar a base de dados assim:

```
USUARIO  set  out  nov  dez

 37      1    1    1    1
 49      1    0    1    0
 107     0    0    1    1
```

Como posso fazer isso? O comando `dummy` seria uma solução?

Segue o dput para ajudar na questão:

```
> dput(head(teste, 50))
structure(list(USUARIO = c(37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 49L, 49L, 
49L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 934L, 934L, 934L, 934L, 934L, 
1116L, 1116L, 1116L, 1116L, 1160L, 1160L, 1160L, 1160L, 1160L, 
1160L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1337L, 1337L, 1337L, 1384L, 
1384L, 1384L, 1384L, 1384L, 1384L, 1532L, 1532L, 1532L, 1532L, 
1532L, 1532L, 1551L, 1551L, 1551L), MÊS = structure(c(1L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("jan", "fev", 
"mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", 
"dez"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), ANO = c(2019, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), compras_mês = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("USUARIO", 
"MÊS"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
    43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(USUARIO = c(37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
934L, 934L, 934L, 934L, 934L, 1116L, 1116L, 1116L, 1116L, 1160L, 
1160L, 1160L, 1160L, 1160L, 1160L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 
1337L, 1337L, 1337L, 1384L, 1384L, 1384L, 1384L, 1384L, 1384L, 
1532L, 1532L, 1532L, 1532L, 1532L, 1532L, 1551L, 1551L, 1551L
), MÊS = structure(c(1L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 
10L), .Label = c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", 
"ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
))), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("USUARIO", 
"MÊS"), drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: @JdMello, obrigado pelas sugestões. Mas você poderia usar os dados do dput que coloquei? Eu consegui chegar no resultado, mas talvez possa ficar confuso para algum outro usuário com a mesma dúvida que eu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podemos usar `data.table` para fazer essa operação:

```
# carregar data.table
library(data.table)

dadosDt <- as.data.table(dados) # transfomar dados em formato data.table

res <- data.table::dcast(dados, USUARIO ~ `MÊS`, fun.aggregate = function(x) 1, value.var = "compras_mês", fill = 0)
```

O que resulta em:

```
> res
   USUARIO jan ago set out nov dez
1       37   1   0   1   1   1   1
2       49   0   0   0   1   1   1
3      107   1   0   1   1   1   1
4      934   1   1   0   1   1   1
5     1116   1   0   0   1   1   1
6     1160   1   1   1   1   1   1
7     1302   0   0   1   1   1   1
8     1337   0   0   0   1   1   1
9     1384   1   1   1   1   1   1
10    1532   1   1   1   1   1   1
11    1551   0   1   1   1   0   0
```

### Explicando a função `data.table::dcast`

A função `data.table::dcast` é bem similar a função do pacote `tidyr::spread`. Você precisar transformar os seus dados de formato "long" para "wide", ou seja, "transpor" valores de certa(s) coluna(s) para colunas. Isso é possível através do argumento `formula` em `data.table::dcast` (ver `?dcast`). O lado esquerdo da formula (no exemplo `USUARIO`) preservará as colunas no formato original com o lado direto (aqui, `MES`) sendo "transposto" para o formato wide. Isso permite que a primeira etapa da transformação ocorra. Entretanto, é preciso preencher os valores nas colunas criadas com os valores de `MES`. Nesse caso, o argumento `value.var` permite que voce escolha qual variavel vai preencher as celulas nas colunas criadas em `MÊS`. Neste caso, você quer preencher `1` caso o usuário tenhe efetuado uma ou mais compras em um dado mês/ano. Por isso usamos `compra_mês` em `value.var`. Finalmente, usamos um "hack"  com a função `fun.aggregate` para que as células sejam preenchidas com `1` se houver uma ou mais occorências em `compras_mês`. Se esse argumento for omitido, `data.table::dcast` fará a contagem de occorrências dos valores no lado direito da fórmula:

> When variable combinations in `formula` doesn't identify a unique value in a cell, `fun.aggregate` will have to be specified, which defaults to `length` if unspecified.

Por isso que é preciso espeficicar `fun.aggregate`, caso contrário `data.table::dcast` retornaria quantas ocorrências tiveram para cada mês e usuário.

Comment: Olá! Esse resultado já tenho. Talvez eu não soube me expressar na pergunta, mas a minha dificuldade é ter uma linha por cada usuário e ter uma coluna por mês. Segundo pesquisas que eu fiz, criar uma variável categórica no meses resolve, mas não sei como posso fazer isso.

Comment: @IzakMandrak Eu dei uma corrigida na minha resposta, não é issoq ue você está procurando?

Comment: não seria isso não. Os meses da minha base está em linha e gostaria deixá-las em colunas, talvez eu esteja perguntando de forma errada, posso refazer a pergunta de forma diferente se precisar.

Comment: tenta isso: `res <- data.table::dcast(dados, USUARIO ~ MES, fun.aggregate = function(x) 1, value.var = "COMPRAS", fill = 0)`

Comment: Você quer transfomar a coluna `MES` em várias colunas em formato dummy/binário? é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Não sei muito sobre o tema, devo reformular a pergunta?

Comment: A pergunta não está mal feita no título, mas esse trecho me confundiu: "Gostaria de saber a quantidade de compras_mês por `USUARIO`". Minha resposta foi atualizada, acho que está correta...

Comment: se vc tiver sugestões e quiser editar a pergunta fique a vontade.

Comment: @JdMello obrigado pelas sugestões. Mas você poderia usar os dados do dput que coloquei? Eu consegui chegar no resultado, mas talvez possa ficar confuso para algum outro usuário com a mesma dúvida que eu. – Izak Mandrak

Comment: só fazer `dados <- dput(...)` e o resultado deve ser replicável.

Comment: Sim. Deu certo.